# SignalR .NET Core - is SAML Token authentication possible?

Tags: .net-core, signalr, saml

Seems like SignalR only accepts Bearer/JWT tokens. Is there support for SAML?

Comment: More info: 

Yes, SignalR's server will accept any authentication scheme. It's SignalR's client libraries that need some finessing to achieve this. There are open issues to add this functionality to both the official JS and C# client libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement SAML in your webapp, the webapp will issue a cookie based on successful authentication. SignalR will [piggyback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-2.2#cookie-authentication) on that:

> In a browser-based app, cookie authentication allows your existing
>   user credentials to automatically flow to SignalR connections. When
>   using the browser client, no additional configuration is needed. If
>   the user is logged in to your app, the SignalR connection
>   automatically inherits this authentication.

Comment: Ah, I failed to mention that this is a service - not user facing. A SAML token will be sent from another service (which is the reason why SAML is being used in the first place - it's an unfortunate requirement of a legacy service)